# Updating graph with deleted children

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I receive an updated graph from the client side and need to update it in DB. The model is a ninja with a collection of equipments.

In DB its like this

```
Ninja id = 1
    Equipments:
        Sword   Id 1
        Candle  Id 2
        Book    Id 3
```

The updated model is like this

```
Ninja id = 1
    Equipments:
        Sword of Metal  Id 1 (Renamed)
        Candle          Id 2
        Gold Nugget     Id 4 (Added)

        The book with id3 is missing cause deleted.
```

So what i try to do with this method is getting to use the same method to add a new ninja if its not an existent one that has changed. This works so i dont need help with this. But what i do need help with is deleting the equipment that is missing in the updated model.

I retrieve a list of all equipments that belong to Id 1 and go through them checking if they exist in the updated model. This iteration seems to add the missing equipment (Book id3) to the updated ninja! I guess its because i attached it. Anyway, then it is never marked as deleted and vill never be deleted.

Why does this happen and how are you supposed to uppdate these kind of graphs in EF?

```
  /// </summary>
    public static string AddNinjaGraph(Ninja uppdatedNinja)
    {
        using (var db = new NinjaDbContext())
        {   
            //Check for id if addNinja is new or updating an old             
            db.Entry(uppdatedNinja).State = uppdatedNinja.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

            foreach (var eq in uppdatedNinja.EquipmentOwned)
            {
                db.Entry(eq).State = eq.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            }

            if (uppdatedNinja.Id > 0)
            {               
                //Go through each ninja equipment belongin to this ninja and delete from DB if its not in the updated ninja graph
                foreach (var eq in db.NinjaEquipment.Where(e => e.Ninja.Id == uppdatedNinja.Id))
                {
                    if (!uppdatedNinja.EquipmentOwned.Contains(eq))
                    {
                        //If ninja in DB has an equipment that updated ninja does not have, delete equipment
                        db.Entry(eq).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    }
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            return uppdatedNinja.Id.ToString();
        }
    }
```